# How to generate a 12 digit number, but all the digits summed together must equal 55?

Tags: python

I'm generating a 12 digit number, but all the digits added together must equal 55.
What is the best way in doing this in python? I can't think of any simple ways. 
Thank you.

Here is what I have tried so far (very time consuming):

```
def isValid(number);
    split = string.split(number)
    if split[0] + split[1] + split[2] + split[3] + split[4] + split[5] + split[6] + split[7] + split[8] + split[9] + split[10] + split[11] == 55:
        return True
    else:
        return False

number = random.randrange(100000000000, 999999999999)

if isValid(number):
    print number
else:
    //Keep generating numbers until you get a valid one
```

Comment: `return 999999100000`.

Comment: @chrisaycock Updated. This isn't homework though, LOL.

Comment: Three lines: `while True:
    n=random.randrange(100000000000, 999999999999)
    if sum(int(e) for e in str(n))==55: break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print them recursively:

```
def gen_num(trailing, depth, left):
    if depth < 11:
        for i in range(max(0,min(10, left))):
            gen_num(trailing*10+i, depth+1, left-i)
    elif depth == 11:
        if left < 10:
            print trailing*10+left

for i in range(1,10):
    gen_num(i, 1, 55-i)
```